# How do I fix Cors policy from blocking requestes with Pathvariables on Angular?

Tags: java, angular, frontend, cors, backend

so basically I am new to Angular and I am trying to send a delete request and a get request that uses path variables.

This is the frontend call:

```
 public deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<void> {
  const options= { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }
  return this.http.delete<void>(` ${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/del/${id}`,options);
 }
 public searchEmployee(id: number) : Observable<Employee>
 {
  const options=  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json',})
  };

  return this.http.get<any>(` ${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/foundid/${id}`);
 }
```

This are the backend methods:

```
    @DeleteMapping("/employee/del/{id}")
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id)
    {

        if(repo.findById(id).isPresent())
        {
            repo.deleteById(id);
            System.out.println("Employee Deleted");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Employee not found");
        }
    }
    @GetMapping("/employee/foundid")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        if(repo.findById(id).isPresent())
        {
            return repo.findById(id).get();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(" Employee not found");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my WebMvcConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    private final long MAX_AGE_SECS = 3600;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer addCorsMappingsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH","DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(MAX_AGE_SECS);
            }
        };

    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/employee/del/[object%20Object]' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I saw the methods works only if the variable was hardcoded like:

```
id=4
return this.http.get<any>(` ${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/foundid/${id}`);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You mention that if you hardcode the id in the `deleteEmployee` function you don't get a error. Looking at the URL from the error you receive it contains `[object%20Object]` . 

Can you verify that you are actually passing a number to the function `deleteEmployee` and not an object.

Comment: By using console.log(id) it appears as 
idemp: 1
[[Prototype]]:  Object
So it seems that i am passing an object but shouldn't id:number specify that id is an int or double variable?

Comment: This is a long shot (I haven't studied Spring's source code closely), but try replacing `allowedHeaders("*")` with `allowedHeaders("Content-Type")`.

Comment: It does not guarantee a number. If the object, as you suggest, has a property `idemp`. Changing the `${id}` to `${id.idemp}` should work. But judging by the code I think you want to make the caller of the function responsible for passing the correct value as a parameter.

I don't think your issue is related to CORS but related to passing the wrong parameter to the function.

Comment: I manage to fix it by doing JSON.Stringify(id) and making the methods in backend receive a String value that was like "{idemp: 1}" Then i manage to generate a substring that takes only the numbers from the sent string and converted it to int, it seems to work this way. Thanks for the help guys I didn't notice that I was sending an object at the beginning s(^.^)-b

Answer (score 0):

I know, you already found a solution, but for anyone else who stumbles across this post: Here are two options on how to enable CORS globally.

#### Prerequisite

I added the cors parameters into my `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: https://localhost:4200
    allowed-headers: cors_allowed_headers:Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization
    allowed-methods: cors_allowed_methods:GET,OPTIONS,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE
    allow-credentials: cors_allow_credentials:false
    max-age: cors_max_age:3600
```

#### 1. Option using Interceptor

You can use an Interceptor that checks the request origin and sets the headers:

```java
public class CORSInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    public static final String HEADER_CREDENTIALS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials";
    public static final String HEADER_ORIGIN_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
    public static final String HEADER_METHODS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
    public static final String HEADER_HEADERS_NAME = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";
    public static final String HEADER_MAX_AGE_NAME = "Access-Control-Max-Age";

    private final Environment env;

    public CORSInterceptor(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler
    ) throws Exception {
        String[] allowedOrigins = this.env.getProperty(WebConfiguration.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, String[].class);
        String allowedHeaders = this.env.getProperty(WebConfiguration.CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        String allowedMethods = this.env.getProperty(WebConfiguration.CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS);
        String allowCredentials = this.env.getProperty(WebConfiguration.CORS_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS);
        String maxAge = this.env.getProperty(WebConfiguration.CORS_MAX_AGE);

        String requestOrigin = request.getHeader("Origin");
        if (Arrays.stream(allowedOrigins).anyMatch(allowedOrigin -> allowedOrigin.equals(requestOrigin))) {
            response.setHeader(HEADER_ORIGIN_NAME, requestOrigin);
        }
        response.setHeader(HEADER_CREDENTIALS_NAME, allowCredentials);
        response.setHeader(HEADER_METHODS_NAME, allowedMethods);
        response.setHeader(HEADER_HEADERS_NAME, allowedHeaders);
        response.setHeader(HEADER_MAX_AGE_NAME, maxAge);
        return true;
    }
}
```

> HINT: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header can only contain one URL. So I need to check, if the request origin is allowed and set the header accordingly.

Then register the interceptor in your WebConfig:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CORSInterceptor());
    }

}
```

#### 2. Option using Configuration

You can also use the `WebMvcConfigurer` directly:

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static final String CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = "spring.cors.allowed-origins";
    public static final String CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS = "spring.cors.allowed-headers";
    public static final String CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS = "spring.cors.allowed-methods";
    public static final String CORS_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS = "spring.cors.allow-credentials";
    public static final String CORS_MAX_AGE = "spring.cors.max-age";

    private final Environment env;

    public WebConfiguration(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        String[] allowedOrigins = this.env.getProperty(CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, String[].class);
        String[] allowedHeaders = this.env.getProperty(CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS, String[].class);
        String[] allowedMethods = this.env.getProperty(CORS_ALLOWED_METHODS, String[].class);
        Boolean allowCredentials = this.env.getProperty(CORS_ALLOWED_CREDENTIALS, Boolean.class);
        Long maxAge = this.env.getProperty(CORS_MAX_AGE, Long.class);

        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(allowedOrigins));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of(allowedMethods));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of(allowedHeaders));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(allowCredentials);
        configuration.setMaxAge(maxAge);

        registry.addMapping("/**").combine(configuration);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Figured our that you only need the interceptor OR the web configuration. I will update my answer accordingly.